# What is the URL for this route?

Tags: magento2, url, router

I created a module with following **admin** routes.xml

> /app/code/UV/Bestellung/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="custom" frontName="custom">
            <module name="UV_Bestellung" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

This is the controller:

> app/code/UV/Bestellung/Adminhtml/Controller/Index

```
<?php
namespace UV\Bestellung\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'Test';
        /*
        $page = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        return $page;
        */
    }
}
```

When I call

> www.mysite.com/admin/custom

it redirects me to the Dashboard.
Can someone tell me what is wrong or what the correct URL is?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: @kiran kumar Your edits are confusing: they seem to be editing the solution into the question, but that makes the answer not make sense. The way this site works is that the question should remain a description of the problem, and the answer to that problem should appear below it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
namespace UV\Bestellung\Adminhtml\Controller\Index;
```

with

```
namespace UV\Bestellung\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
```

Comment: kese kar lete ho ye sab????? talent ha baki.... :D